# QGIS2 to QGIS3 plugin migration issue AttributeError: type object 'QObject' has no attribute 'connect'

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-2, pyqt5, pyqt4

I am trying to migrate a plugin. I have these two lines:

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.buttonBox, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("accepted()")), Configuration.accept)
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.buttonBox, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("rejected()")), Configuration.reject)
```

I thought after looking into some examples that in PyQt5 the lines should read:

```
self.QObject.connect(self.buttonBox, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("accepted()")), Configuration.accept)
self.QObject.connect(self.buttonBox, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("rejected()")), Configuration.reject)
```

but it just throws the error

```
AttributeError: 'ConfigurationDialog' object has no attribute 'QObject'
```

This is confusing because ConfigurationDialog is not found in this py script. ConfigurationDialog is a class in another script but nowhere in it does it make reference to QObject. Can I get some clarification on what where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With [this documentation](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html#connecting-disconnecting-and-emitting-signals) about PyQt5 signals, try this :

```
self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(Configuration.accept)
self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(Configuration.reject)
```

Comment: Thank you; I really need to do a python3 and pyQt5 course I would never have gotten that.

Answer (score 1):

I can't really tell you why the error message occurs, because I can't see your full code. But to solve your problem, try creating the `Signal`/`Slot` connection like this:

```
self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(Configuration.accept)
self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(Configuration.reject)
```

I hope this helps