# QGIS 2 to 3 (QObject.connect)

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-3

I can't seem to port this line to QGIS 3.0 API

> QObject.connect(self.dlg.ui.chkActivate,SIGNAL("stateChanged(int)"),self.toggle_activate)

Any ideas? I believe QObject is deprecated.

Comment: Try with `self.dlg.ui.chkActivate.stateChanged.connect(self.toggle_activate)`

Comment: You can also check the migration guide https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/wiki/Plugin-migration-to-QGIS-3 Duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/317489 too